# Streamlit Docker does not opens up using internal URL but rather localhost

Tags: docker, ubuntu, apple-m1, streamlit

Here's the reproducible example

### Dockerfile

```
Dockerfile
FROM python:3.8
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install streamlit
ENTRYPOINT ["streamlit", "run", "app.py"]
```

### Docker Commands used

```
docker build -t streamlit-app:latest .
docker run -ti streamlit-app:latest
```

Weirdly enough, it works using the network port provided by Streamlit (in Docker installed in my system with Ubuntu), but I have to use the localhost:8501 on my system with M1 mac.

Does it have something to do with the issue?

Comment: Just for the record, that's not reproducible since we don't have the files that get copied into the container with `COPY . /app`.

Comment: Your `docker run` command doesn't have a `-p` option.  If the application reports that it's listening or reachable on some address you don't recognize (`172.17.0.2:8501`?) that's a Docker-internal address, which will happen to work on native Linux from the same host but not anywhere else.  Using a `-p` option and `localhost` (or the containing system's DNS name) is normal practice.

Comment: @HansKilian Thanks for the headsup, removed the `COPY . /app` as there were no additional files.

Comment: @DavidMaze When the same process is performed on Linux (Ubuntu), the application reported address (also called as the Network URL by streamlit), is reachable by a browser. But the same does not happen on my mac system.

Comment: That address is only usable on native-Linux systems, and then only when you're on the same physical host.  Using a `docker run -p` published ports works on all host OSes.  Also see "Per-container IP addressing is not possible" in the [Docker Desktop for Mac documentation](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/mac/networking/#per-container-ip-addressing-is-not-possible).